# How to make second textarea required only if first textarea is filled

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to make `desg` textarea as required only if `name` textarea is filled.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="name"  name="name" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('ref15').innerHTML = this.value"></textarea>

<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="desg" name="desg" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('ref16').innerHTML = this.value"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the keyup event of `#name` check it's value. If value exist then add `required` attribute to `#desg` else remove.

```js
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    $('#ref15').html(this.value);

    var desg = $('#desg');

    if (this.value.trim()) {
        desg.attr('required', 'required');
    } else {
        desg.removeAttr('required');
    }
});

$('#desg').keyup(function() {
    $('#ref16').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="name" name="name"></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="desg" name="desg"></textarea>
```

Comment: I have updated my code since I already have another inline keyup function for another thing... if so will this also work? pls advice

Comment: Remove inline keyup and try like updated answer. @Tharuperera